# What is the easy way to create django form

Tags: django, django-forms

For example I have got the Student model

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
    learning_group = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
```

So I want to create the following form for each student in some group:

| Student | Mark | Absent |

| John Smyth | input for mark | input for absent hours|

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:

I am storing my absent and mark fields in JSonField() and it look like this
**{ student_pk: 1, mark: 5, absent: 3 }**
So what did I tried:

At first I tried to implement this through overriding forms.Form **init** method but it was formatted wrong

```
def MarkBookForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.students = kwargs.pop('students', None)
        super(MarkBookForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for student in self.students:
            self.fields["student_{}".format(student.pk)] = forms.CharField(initial="{} {}".format(student.first_name, student.last_name)
            self.fields["mark_{}".format(student.pk)] = forms.FloatField()
            self.fields["absent_{}".format(student.pk)] = forms.FloatField()
```

This is what I want
[image]

And this what i did

[image]

Comment: Please describe `mark` and `absent` fields

Comment: What have you tried/researched? Forms are *highly* detailed throughout the django documentation.

Comment: Yes i tried but without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should define your model for `mark` and `absent`
You can use sth like this( not tested :) ):

```
models.py:

    class MyModel(models.Model):
        field1 = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=False)
        field2 = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)

forms.py:

    class FormForMyModel(forms.Form):
        form_field1 = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=True)
        form_field2 = forms.CharField(max_length=60, required=False)

views.py:

    def create_a_my_model(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = FormForMyModel(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                my_model = MyModel()
                my_model.field1 = form.cleaned_data.get('form_field1', 'default1')
                my_model.field2 = form.cleaned_data.get('form_field2', 'default2')
                my_model.save()
        else:        
            form = FormForMyModel()
        context_data = {'form': form}
        return HttpResponse('templtate.html', context_data)
```

The above example outlines generic form workflow.

You can notice two annoying issues in the above example:

1. I have to define Fields on `MyModel` and Fields on `FormForMyModel` separately. However, there is a lot of similarity between those two groups (types) of Fields, so that's kind of duplicate work. The similarity grows when adding labels, validators, etc.
2. creating of `MyModel` instance is a bit silly, having to assign all those values manually.

This is where a **ModelForm** comes in.

So back to the two issues:

1. Instead of defining a form Field for each model Field, I simply define `model = MyModel` in the the `Meta` class. This instructs the Form to automatically generate form Fields from model Fields.
2. Model forms have `save` method available. This can be used to create instance of model in one line in the view, instead of manually assigning field-by-field.

So, lets make the example above with a `ModelForm`:

```
models.py:

    class MyModel(models.Model):
        field1 = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=False)
        field2 = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)

forms.py:

    class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):  # extending ModelForm, not Form as before
        class Meta:
            model = MyModel

views.py:

    def create_a_my_model(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                # save the model to database, directly from the form:
                my_model = form.save()  # reference to my_model is often not needed at all, a simple form.save() is ok
                # alternatively:
                # my_model = form.save(commit=False)  # create model, but don't save to database
                # my.model.something = whatever  # if I need to do something before saving it
                # my.model.save()
        else:        
            form = MyModelForm()
        context_data = {'form': form}
        return HttpResponse('templtate.html', context_data)
```

Comment: I'll remove my answer as this is much more comprehensive then mine. Good answer.